# Can I retrieve addtional LDAP objects during authentication with Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, ldap

I am using `.htaccess` and Apache v2.4 with `mod_authnz_ldap` to force LDAP authentication to our local Domain Controller.  The following block works just fine and the access log also includes the userID.

```
# LDAP stuff
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Validate with User ID"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldapServer.com:389 DC=global,DC=myCoName,DC=com?sAMAccountName"
AuthLDAPBindDN "myDomain\\ServiceAccountName"
AuthLDAPBIndPassword "ServiceAccountPassword"
require valid-user
```

Using the `phpinfo.php` script, the Apache Environmental Variable `AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME` is set to the userID.

What I need is to also retrieve additional user data such as full name, phone number, etc. or if is easier, return the complete record for the userID without using PHP or some other back-end.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, the answer is given in the Apache docs.  For authentication purposes, only the first attribute listed is used for authentication.  Any additional (Comma separated) attributes are fetched during the authentication process.

Modifying the `LDAPAuthURL` to:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldapServer.com:389 DC=global,DC=myCoName,DC=com?sAMAccountName,displayName,givenName,sn"
```

authenticates on `sAMAccountName` but also returns the `dispalyName`, `givenName`, and the surname `sn`.  These values are then found in the Apache envrionment prefixed by `AUTHENTICATE_`.  PHP variables are prefixed with `_SERVER["AUTHENTICATE_*`

As an example, this is what is returned when I login:

```
AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME al2
AUTHENTICATE_DISPLAYNAME    Lindberg, Alex (Alex)
AUTHENTICATE_GIVENNAME      Alex
AUTHENTICATE_SN             Lindberg
```

and

```
_SERVER["AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME"] al2 
_SERVER["AUTHENTICATE_DISPLAYNAME"]    Lindberg, Alex (Alex) 
_SERVER["AUTHENTICATE_GIVENNAME"]      Alex 
_SERVER["AUTHENTICATE_SN"]             Lindberg
```

A listing of attributes can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Does your LDAP server assign its users any group membership, and did you pass along any group membership data in environment variables?